# Remove object from json response Android

Tags: java, android, json

Hello guys I need your help. How do I remove this from my json response?

```
[
  {
    "Woa": [
        "Seo",
        "Rikjeo",
        "JDa"
    ]
  },
"Aha",
"Aad",
"Char"
]
```

I want to remove this:

```
{
    "Woa": [
        "Seo",
        "Rikjeo",
        "JDa"
    ]
  }
```

This is what I tried so far:

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); ++i) {
    list.add(array.getString(i));
}

list.remove(0);
```

But it is still not removed. How do I do that? Any ideas will be greatly appreciated

Edited list.remove(1) to (0)

Comment: So you want to turn valid JSON data into an invalid one?

Comment: you can assume it as a jsonarray and then fetch the object on 0 index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After removing the item you need to create the JSON again using the list.

```
list.remove(1);

JSONArray jsArray = new JSONArray(list);
```

If you want to convert JSONArray to JSON string:

```
jsArray.toString()
```

Comment: after jsArray will I loop again?

Comment: if you want to process the array further then only.

Comment: This exact problem I encounter at my colleagues almost every day: they tend to solve issues SO specifically, that if they if the original problem then slightly changes, their "fix" won't work anymore. Or more, if they find the  same problem in a different place under slightly different circumstances, they have to make it all over again. Their code just works for exactly ONE case of the issue. And that's exactly what this answer does. Programmers need to understand this: they need to code and solve things in a GENERALLY manner so that they won't have to copy paste 50% of the code in one project

Comment: thanks, but this doesn't the case for one case. Its upto you how you take it if you understand that if you modified the list created from JSONArray then you have to build the JSONArray using the modified list in GENERAL.

Comment: Yep, this code is very general, especially this line: list.remove(1);

Answer (score 0):

> Your list will be updated, not your JSON object.

Why don't you use a `JSONparser`.

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(mystring);
obj.remove("entryname");
```

Answer (score 0):

You should make something that's more general so you don't have to modify your code EVERY time the JSON changes. For example:

```
        //here we create the JSONArray object from the string that contains the json data
        JSONArray array = new JSONArray(myJsonString);

        //here we create a list that represents the final result - a list of Strings
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

        //here we parse every object that the JSONArray contains
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {

            //if the current item is an JSONObject, then we don't need it, so we continue our iteration 
            //this check is not necessary because of the below check, 
            //but it helps you see things clearly: we IGNORE JSONObjects from the array
            if (array.get(i) instanceof JSONObject) {
                continue;
            }

            //if our current object is a String, we add it to our final result
            if (array.get(i) instanceof String) {
                list.add(array.getString(i));
            }
        }
```

Comment: Can you explain each line? Thanks

Comment: I've edited so you can understand better. Check again

Comment: That's not true at all. I tested this code before pasting it here. And I invite you to test it as well. JSONArray doesn't only contain JSONObject. It can contain one of the: Boolean, JSONArray, JSONObject, Number, String, or the JSONObject.NULL object. You should read some java doc :)

Answer (score 0):

One problem is that the element you are trying to remove is the first one, and the index of the first element of a `JSONArray` object is zero.

You are calling `list.remove(1)` which removes the second element of the array.

The following should be sufficient:

```
list.remove(0);
```

... without the stuff prior to it.

If this is not working, then my guess is that you are removing the element too late; i.e. *after* the `JSONArray` object has been serialized.  However, we need to see more (relevant) code to be sure.

---

The Android documentation for `JSONArray` fails to mention that array indexing is zero-based.  However, it is.  I checked the source code.  Furthermore most other Java data structures (arrays, lists etcetera) use zero-based indexing.  (A notable exception is Java data structures modelled on the W3C DOM APIs.)

Answer (score 0):

you can parse your string to JSONArray, the first element of the array is what you want.

```
@Test
public void test() {
    String str = "[  {\"Woa\": [\"Seo\",\"Rikjeo\",\"JDa\"]},\"Aha\",\"Aad\",\"Char\"]";
    try {
    JSONArray array;
        array = new JSONArray(str);
        System.out.println(array);
        System.out.println(array.get(0));
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

> [{"Woa":["Seo","Rikjeo","JDa"]},"Aha","Aad","Char"]
>
> {"Woa":["Seo","Rikjeo","JDa"]}
>
> PASSED: test

Answer (score 0):

**You Can one by one remove**

```
 while (user_data.length() > 0) {
  user_data.remove(user_data.keys().next());
 }
```